# GetProcAddress returnning null for remote process for windowds xp

Tags: visual-c++

I have injected one of my dll in many process.What I want to do is call the function in that dll from my application in all the process in which it is loaded. I used following codes.It works fine in windows vista+ OS but it get failed at line GetProcAddress() in windows xp...why this is happening please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
const TCHAR * pszDllName = _T("MyDll.dll");
void CallProcessFunc( DWORD processID,LPCSTR funcName)
{
    // Get a handle to the process.
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | 
                                   PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD,
                                   FALSE, processID );

    if(hProcess == NULL)
        return;


    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    DWORD cbNeeded;


    if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded) )
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)(cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++ )
        {
            TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
            // Get the full path to the module's file.
            if ( GetModuleFileNameEx( hProcess, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)) == FALSE)
                continue;

            if(_tcsstr(szModName, pszDllName) == NULL)
                continue;

            LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpRoutine = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ::GetProcAddress(hMods[i], funcName);// here it get failed in windows xp
            if(lpRoutine == NULL)
                continue;

            HANDLE hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0,  lpRoutine, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if(hRemoteThread == NULL)
                continue;

            WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
            DWORD ret = 0;
            GetExitCodeThread(hRemoteThread, &ret);
            CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);

            break;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}




void fnCallRemoteFuntion()
{
    LPCSTR fuctName = "NotifyDll";

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded = 0;
    EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded );
    int cProcesses = (int)(cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD));
    for (int i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] == 0 )
            continue;

        CallProcessFunc(aProcesses[i], fuctName);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution from an article for which link is given.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/139349/Getting-the-address-of-a-function-in-a-DLL-loaded

i was using GetProcAddress function which was incorrect Bcoz it is giving proc address in current process not in remote process and my need was getting proc address in remote thread,which is explain in above link.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"**Provide context for links**: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link**, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*